# Hyper Strings InterviewStreet: Python

Tags: python, algorithm

https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4f802ebfad2a1
My Code is passing 6/10 test cases.

```
from collections import Counter
j,k = map(int, raw_input().split())

y = Counter(len(raw_input()) for i in range(j))

saved = {}

def f(x):
    if x in saved:  return saved[x]
    if x<1: return 0
    k = y[x] if x in y else 0
    for i in y:
        k += y[i]*f(x-i)
   saved[x] = k
   return k
x = 0
for i in xrange(1,k+1):
    x+=f(i)

print (x+1)%1000000007
```

Key in 'y' is length of super string and its Value is number of super strings with that length in set 'H'.

'saved' handles memoization.

f(x) calculates hyper strings of length x. I iterate through all values in last 'for loop'.

x has result except empty string (''), therefore x+1

Comment: You should try and do a bit more work on this problem before bringing it to SO -- what have you tried? Can you follow through the execution of the code? What is it doing, in English?

Answer (score 2):

I think this code fails in the cases when any super string is concat of any other super strings.
In this case, this code will add some cases multiple times.
Eg:

```
3 2
a
b
ab
```

Your Output : 8
Right Output : 7
Double Counting of "ab"
I am myself trying the question, will post the answer in case it scores 10/10

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is my code . I have used your code as algorithm, but removed super strings that can be formed by concatenation of other super strings.
Thanks for posting your problem, my original code before seeing this post was terribly un-optimal. 
Any suggestion to further optimize this is welcome.

```
from collections import Counter
j,k = map(int, raw_input().split())

supers_list = []

for i in range(j):
    supers_list.append(raw_input())

def check_concat(Str_, Sub_Str_):
    if Sub_Str_ == "":
        return False

    for i in supers_list:
        if i == Sub_Str_ and Str_ != Sub_Str_:
        return True
    x = Sub_Str_.startswith(i)
    if x == True:
        if check_concat(Str_, Sub_Str_[len(i):]) == True:
            return True
return False

def filter_():
    tmp = []
    global supers_list
    for i in supers_list:
        if check_concat(i,i) == False:
            tmp.append(i)
    supers_list = tmp

filter_()

y = Counter(len(i) for i in supers_list)

saved = {}

def f(x):
    if x in saved:  return saved[x]
    if x<1: return 0
    k = y[x] if x in y else 0
    for i in y:
        k += y[i]*f(x-i)
    saved[x] = k
    return k
x = 0
for i in xrange(1,k+1):
    x+=f(i)

print (x+1)%1000000007
```